# Surface Pro (W8.1) shut down after WindowsUpdateClient events

Tags: windows-8, event-log

My Surface Pro 2 running Windows 8.1 shut down last night for no apparent reason.

Between 9:32 PM and 9:36 PM the eventlog logged this (red) error:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application [...] This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

There were dozens of these messages, most coming it at the very same second in blocks.

The last messages in the system event log were from WindowsUpdateClient, again a few times (but not several dozen times like the above).

```
Installation Ready: The following updates are downloaded and ready for installation. To install the updates, an administrator should log on to this computer and Windows will prompt with further instructions: 
- Microsoft.Internal.Media.PlayReadyClient
- Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview.Internal
- Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview
- Microsoft.WinJS.Preview.1
- Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Preview.Internal
```

When I logged in after starting, I couldn't see any updates ready for installation.

The last Windows update message above was from 9:44:59 PM.

Oddly enough the first event from source EventLog when I started up the computer was

```
The previous system shutdown at 21:23:50 on ‎14/‎01/‎2014 was unexpected.
```

Apparently EventLog believes the system shut down at 21:23 but that it wrote events from WindowsUpdateClient for 20 minutes afterwards.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: That "previous system shutdown" message isn't logged until the next time the computer boots.  So it shutdown due to some unexpected reason, and then started up again and continued logging errors.

Comment: But it didn't continue logging errors. It logged one error after boot and that error got the time of the shutdown wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a crash/BlueScreen during Windows Update processing (I am pretty sure you have the settings set to download and install automatically).

However if this happens reboot should occur, not shut down. I seen the same update about 2 days ago and the behavior was that the device rebooted 4 times - while installing the updates. For a moment I thought it got stuck in never ending reboot boot where it would get to the login screen only to switch to "shutting down" screen immediately.

I am going to guess that the event log shutdown was the first one initiated after the update install and the issue came up during one of the following reboots that I have seen and it never recovered.

I would save the log and clear it. Next I would check if the listed updates are installed - if they are I would not worry unless it happens again. If they are not I would guess the update info is corrupted and would do restore to 1 day before and try the update again.

Comment: No, I disabled automatic updates. It also didn't actually download any updates as far as I could tell. I later ran the update and it found a few updates, downloaded them and installed them, but not those listed in the event.

Comment: If you have those disabled than the updates should never be displayed and you either downloaded them manually or they would come from other rogue location.

Comment: The updates never were displayed, only mentioned in the eventlog.